# Access images from local JSON file on the web page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

Where am i going wrong?

I want to access images from datahl.json file on the web page but unable to access them.Please check the codes and help me. 
If possible please refer the solution to plunker editor.

**index.html**

```
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat = "hbl in hbls">
            <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat = "h in hbl.data_list" 
                 style="width:100%;">
              <img ng-src="{{h.img}}" alt="" style="height:50vh;">
                 <div class="caption">   
                    <p><strong>{{h.name}}</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**app.js** This is my js codes

```
 var app = angular.module('hostellApp', []);
app.controller('hostellController', function($scope, hblsFactory){
    $scope.hbls;

    hblsFactory.getHbls().then(function(response){
       $scope.hbls = response.data; 
    });

    $scope.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("Hello");
    }
});

    app.factory('hblsFactory', function($http){

        function getHbls(){
            return $http.get('datahl.json');
        }

        return {
            getHbls: getHbls
        }
    });
```

**datahl.json** This is my local JSON file

`
  {

```
    "view_type": 5,
    "title": "Hostels By Locality",
    "position": 5,
    "data_list":
   [

        {
            "img": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images-city- 
                    teens/IMG_20180526_1139570.8091572935412125.jpg",
            "name": "Mahavir Nagar"
        },
        {
            "img": "https://graph.facebook.com/1666751513414902/picture? 
                          type=large",
            "name": null
        },
        {
            "img": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images-city- 
                            teens/cropped1148015742983667713.jpg",
            "name": "New Rajiv Gandhi"
        },
        {
            "img": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images-city- 
                         teens/cropped998427941.jpg",
            "name": "Jawahar Nagar"
        }

    ]
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you get from your JSON file is not an array but an object. This means that you only need one `ng-repeat`.

Change your first `ng-repeat` to `ng-repeat="h in hbls.data_list"`(added an 's' to hbl) and delete your second `ng-repeat`.

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OOd1M1dNFjSB7uaqZZB6?p=preview